# VCO from near-0 Hz to 100 MHz

Tags: pll, vco

Anyone know of a VCO which can range from close to 0 Hz up to around 100 MHz ?

I have tried the 4046A IC, however am having trouble getting enough high frequency out of it.

Comment: A VCO that does 0 Hz is not a VCO because the O in VCO stands for **O**scillator. 0 Hz is not an oscillation. Go on Mouser or Farnell and search for VCOs which can do 100 MHz, can any of these go down to 0 Hz? I doubt it.

Comment: Close to 0 Hz.. Do you mean 0.0001 Hz or so?

Comment: A DDS that's clocked at 250 MHz or more and is followed by a good anti-alias / reconstruction filter will produce that range. Get an Analog Devices development board for one that's ready built, from the AD991x series for instance. Alternatively get a 50-100MHz VCO (minicircuits is my goto supplier for cheap RF components) followed by a cascade of octave digital dividers to get to down to as low as you want. Alternatively get a 400-500 MHz VCO and a fixed 500 MHz oscillator, and beat the two together. The output frequency at low frequency will be proportionately very unstable though.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the datasheet of 4046A.

[image]

[image]

There is no chance at all to reach 100 MHz. You need a small capacitor of 10 pF and a small resistor of 2.2 kOhm for more than 10 MHz.

For a low frequency below 10 Hz you need a large capacitor of 100 nF and a large resistor of 11 MOhm.

You can't get a frequency below 1 Hz as well as above 10 MHz using the same capacitor and resistor for the VCO. This is true not only for a 4046A but also for any other VCO. A frequency range of more than 6 decades is not possible using the same RC combination for the VCO.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which specifically is: "Anyone know of a VCO which can range from close to 0 Hz up to around 100 MHz?". This is at best a comment on their 'aside' note. Downvoting for those reasons, I'm afraid.